# Riddle that I got and cannot solve(3 Knocks)

Tags: riddle

Well in this riddle there's a word or phrase as an answer, its from a game,
I cannot solve it so far(over a week trying).
The riddle is the following:

"Try not to move, 3 knocks and you're outside."

Context:
This is a game where you get a riddle and you need to answer a word or a sentence in order to pass to the next level, there are no clues.
Example of last riddle was : “The first in the series, since Daniel became a legend” and the answer was “Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone”.There is no credit needed, it is a family game...

Comment: Did you hear or read this? The reason I ask: If you heard it, then maybe it was actually "knocks" rather than "Knocks" or "you're" rather than "your". That could change the riddle substantially.

Comment: @msh210 hey, it was written “knocks” and “your’e” I just had a typo. Thanks

Comment: When you say a game, do you mean like a video game? My first instinct is to say it's telling you to keep your character still for some amount of time. The "knocks" is probably referring to a sound that gets triggered as a warning if you move too much. I think we need more info about the game the "riddle" came from

Comment: @AnthonyIngram-Westover this is a textual game, you need to write a word or sentence which is the answer...

Comment: Is there a theme - for example names of books/movies? Or can the answers be anything at all?

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica there is no theme, answers can be anything, even though the last riddle was about harry potter(as you can see in the example I gave)

Comment: Voting to reopen. Whether or not this is actually answerable or a good puzzle, the "attribution" close reason certainly doesn't apply any more.

Comment: Worth noting that 3 knocks is commonly an omen of death in Irish and Scottish culture...

Comment: Are there any answers that you've tried and been told were wrong? Might be useful to help narrow it down...

Comment: might be some kids game like the freeze one. where we freeze or maybe some horror movie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is

> Race

Reasoning:

> The "do not move" line is common practice at the start of most races, be them horse, car, or track. All the contestants line up at the beginning and wait for the signal. In horse and car races (not sure if this is common practice for track) three sounds ("knocks") are used to signal "on your mark", "get set", and "go".

Answer (score 1):

The 3 knocks are

> [an omen of death in Irish and Scottish culture](https://national-paranormal-society.org/three-knocks-scared/).

Beyond this, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know this is relevant but...

> It is the name of a different fantasy book by an English author: https://www.bookdepository.com/Wizards-Once-Knock-Three-Times-Cressida-Cowell/9781444941456